# Why does Firefox console only quote some object keys?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning about computed properties in JavaScript. I made a list of my players from my favorite baseball team and tried using object literals. Some of the positions are showing up as strings and some are not? Does anyone have an explanation for this? My only guess is it has something to do with the Mozilla console.

```
const position1 = "Pitcher";
const position2 = "Catcher";
const position3 = "First Base";
const position4 = "Second Base";
const position5 = "Third Base";
const position6 = "Shortstop";
const position7 = "Left Field";
const position8 = "Center Field";
const position9 = "Right Field";

const player1 = "Jacob deGrom";
const player2 = "Wilson Ramos";
const player3 = "Pete Alonso";
const player4 = "Robinson Cano";
const player5 = "Jeff Mcneil";
const player6 = "Amed Rosario";
const player7 = "JD Davis";
const player8 = "Brandon Nimmo";
const player9 = "Michael Conforto";


const team = {
  [position1]: player1,
  [position2]: player2,
  [position3]: player3,
  [position4]: player4,
  [position5]: player5,
  [position6]: player6,
  [position7]: player7,
  [position8]: player8,
  [position9]: player9,
};
```

And the console output is as follows:

```
Catcher: "Wilson Ramos"
​
"Center Field": "Brandon Nimmo"
​
"First Base": "Pete Alonso"
​
"Left Field": "JD Davis"
​
Pitcher: "Jacob deGrom"
​
"Right Field": "Michael Conforto"
​
"Second Base": "Robinson Cano"
​
Shortstop: "Amed Rosario"
​
"Third Base": "Jeff Mcneil"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

​

Comment: That's just the way the console works. All property names are *always* strings. The console shows them with quote characters to make it clear that they're not valid *identifiers* even though they're valid property names.

Comment: (Correction: now property names can also be Symbol instances, but that's clearly not relevant to this question.)

Comment: You notice the that the ones in quotes have spaces while the others don't

Comment: There're many console implementations. If you create a runnable snippet you'll see tha Stack Overflow's quotes *all* keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the property names shown in quotes are the ones that would not be valid with dot notation, which are, in your case, all the ones with spaces.

For example, `obj.Catcher = "something"` is valid, but `obj.Center Field` produces a syntax error and such a property can only be set or accessed using square brackets, i.e. `obj["Center Field"]`.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: Thank you! Perfect explanation I didn't even catch the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an implementation detail. Firefox mimics the actual literal object syntax, where keys that aren't valid identifiers need to be quoted:

```js
var o = {
  one: 1,
  "and two": 2
};
console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Building up on what hev1 wrote.  In Javascript a string is evaluated in different ways depending upon how it is written.  A variable passed to an Object is evaluated as a string. If you pass it a number it too is evaluated as a string unless it's a boolean, NaN, or null value. You can't use .notation on a string and you can't have white space. I am sure this is why camelCase is an important naming convention. If you want to use one convention for accessing the values inside your team Object consider writing "First Base" as "firstBase" or "First_Base".
`console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(team["First Base"])) console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(team.Catcher))`
Hope this helps?